# Get already used shortcuts in QGIS plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, c++, qt

I have a c++ plugin in QGIS which contains a treewidget. Now I want to get the keyPress-events. Until now I get this with the eventfilter described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/44280/13507)

My problem is, I want to use shortcuts like *Ctrl-N* to create a new treewidgetitem. But this shortcut is used by QGIS self for creating a new document and it doesn't goes through my eventfilter. Knows someone a trick to get the event, if the focus is at my plugin-treewidget?

Comment: Try going to the menubar `Settings > Configure shortcuts...`, highlight the "New" action and click the **Set none** button. Close the interface and restart QGIS then see if your plugin works with the shortcut.

Comment: This worked for me but I could not do this for all shortcuts I want to use and not for all customers using the plugin. I also don't want to change it for QGIS, only for my plugin.